# Creating a List and Summing Attribute in that list of Python Objects

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class of objects with attribute length. Point class has a (x,y) point and Line class takes these two points and calculate distance between 2 Cartesian (x,y) point and gives a length of line. And I want to create a polygon classes that contain empty list and gets Line values from Line class and add to the list. Any suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.__x=float(x)
        self.__y=float(y)

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__y

    @property
    def calculation(self):
        return (self.__x,self.__y)

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in (self.calculation):
            yield i

class Line(object):
    def __init__(self,fromPoint,toPoint):
        self.__fromPoint= tuple(fromPoint)
        self.__toPoint= tuple(toPoint)

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self.__length

    def calc(self):
        self.__length = ((self.__fromPoint[0] - self.__toPoint[0]) + (self.__fromPoint[1] - self.__toPoint[1]))**0.5

class Polygon(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__segments= []
        self.__length= float(length)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, than something like that is that what you need:

```
class Polygon(object):
    def __init__(self, *points):
        self.points = points
        self.lines = []

    def create():
        points = self.points
        i = 0
        while i < len(points):
            if i + 1 == len(points):
                line = Line(points[i], points[0])
                self.lines.append(line)
                break
            line = Line(points[i], points[i + 1])
            self.lines.append(line)
            i += 1
```